# Likelihood of sum of log-normal and normal distribution

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, likelihood, lognormal-distribution

Given $y(x_t)=e^{f(x_t)}-\varepsilon _t$ 
with $\varepsilon _t\sim N(0,4e^{f(x_t)})$ 
 and $f\sim GP(\mu,\sum)$. 
 What is the likelihood $p(y|f)$? Is it $p(y|f)\sim N(e^{f(x_t)},4e^{f(x_t)})$? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: indeed, $p(y_t|f)\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\exp(f(x_t)),4\exp(f(x_t))\right)$.